# Django Nested Serilizer with post method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have successfully created my serializer class with class with django and it works very nice only for `GET` Method but i need also `POST` method should work.

Currently Post method not working...

this is my serializer class:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import Author, Article, Category, Organization


class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = '__all__'


class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    organization = OrganizationSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer()
    category = CategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model =  Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

Above snippet working only for GET method, not for POST Method...

I need it should work for post method..

---

If you dont understand above serilizers, you can see my models:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

class Organization(models.Model):
    organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.organization_name

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    detail = models.TextField()
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
    alias = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Can anyone tell me what should i include to make my end point work for post method?

**This is the error i see, it is from terminal:**

```
 File "/home/pyking/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 823, in raise_errors_on_nested_writes
    class_name=serializer.__class__.__name__
AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `blog2.serializers.ArticleSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
[23/Jun/2019 12:22:49] "POST /blog2/api/v1/article HTTP/1.1" 500 122369
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[23/Jun/2019 12:22:49] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2186
```

Comment: Can you add error stacktrace of what exactly isn't working?

Comment: I edited the post with error message, please check the post again, the error stacktrace given

Answer (score 0):

As the error stacktrace says, you should implement `create()` in your serializer class. It is a common case when dealing with nested serialization in DRF.

One solution of this problem is defining different serializers for **reading** and **writing** data. That means one serializer for fetching resources and one for creating/updating them.

---

At first, define a `ModelSerializer` you would use for standard writing operations (*POST* / *PUT* / *PATCH*):

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Important: Remove your nested serializers declaration here!

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then extend this serializer and override the fields you want to get with nested serialization (*GET*):

```
class ArticleReadSerializer(ArticleSerializer):
     author = AuthorSerializer(read_only=True)
     category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)

     # Note the read_only=True parameters in both serializers
     # And the class you inherit from
```

Then specify the serializer you wish to use for different operations for your `APIView` / `ViewSet` via overriding [`get_serializer_class`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0407a0df8a16fdac94bbd08d49143a74a88001cd/rest_framework/generics.py#L112):

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = Article.objects.all()

     def get_serializer_class(self):
         if self.request.method in ['GET']:
             return ArticleReadSerializer

         return ArticleSerializer
```

This is an example with `ModelViewSet`, but this method exists in every generic view class in DRF, thus it is transferable mechanism.

---

Now you can create articles by specifying related models with their **primary keys**:

```
{
    "title": "...",
    "author": 1,
    "category": 1
}
```

---

*Note*: You should also set `organization = OrganizationSerializer(read_only=True)` in your `AuthorSerializer` since you have already created an author with related organization and do not create a new organization entry when creating an article.